# What can I do with the lifting the exponent lemma?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

What can I do with LTE (lifting the exponent lemma)?

[If you don't know LTE lemma visit here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Lifting_The_Exponent_Lemma)
or [here](http://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiflf2lh8_SAhWJ2LwKHTjAAuIQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fservices.artofproblemsolving.com%2Fdownload.php%3Fid%3DYXR0YWNobWVudHMvYy82LzdjNTI1OGIyMmNjYmZkZGY4MDhhY2ViZTc3MGE1NDRmMzFhMTEzLnBkZg%3D%3D%26rn%3DTGlmdGluZyBUaGUgRXhwb25lbnQgTGVtbWEgLSBBbWlyIEhvc3NlaW4gUGFydmFyZGkgLSBWZXJzaW9uIDMucGRm&usg=AFQjCNHpxCf9vA-wAEp4FMEWwWjuXzU_4A&sig2=j5_5WWa4dNg6xujsNjyxiQ&bvm=bv.149397726,d.dGc)

Answer (score 4):

Assume some positive integers $a,b$ with $a \gt b$ and $gcd(a,b)=1$.
Then consider the primefactorization of $f(n) = a^n - b^n $ where $n$ is again positive integer, with $m$ primefactors 
$$ f(n) = p_1^{e_1} \cdot p_2^{e_2} \cdot \ldots p_m^{e_m} 
$$
Then the LTE gives you a formula, how to compute the exponents $e_k$ by a function  depending on a given $n$ (and on properties of the prime $p_k$). Essentially this formula *"algebraicalizes"* the little theorem of Fermat and Euler's totient-theorem.
This little *"LTE-algebra"* can help to express exponential diophantine problems much more concise and possibly to find solutions (or a space of solutions) easier

---

I've made an essay about this problem (however not knowing the name "LTE" and having developed my own notations), see [here](http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/CyclicSubgroups.pdf) . It is still partly in "draft mode" , but is meant to give examples and make the whole problem much transparent and intuitive.