# $a \equiv b$ (mod $p$) implies $a^{p^n} \equiv b^{p^n}$ (mod $p^n$)?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $p$ be a prime number. If $a \equiv b$ (mod $p$), does that imply $a^{p^n} \equiv b^{p^n}$ (mod $p^n$)?

I think the answer will be yes, and I suspect that the way of proving it will involve writing  $a^{p^n}-b^{p^n}$ as a multiple of $(a-b)^n$.

I also noticed that $n<p^n$, and I'm wondering if this will make the proof easier or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a=b+kp$ where $k$ is an integer

$(b+kp)^{p^n}=b^{p^n}+\binom{p^n}1b^{p^n-1}kp+\binom{p^n}2b^{p^n-2}(kp)^{2}+\cdots+(kp)^{p^n}$

$\equiv b^{p^n}\pmod{p^{n+1}}$

Comment: So simple yet so useful! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is following theorem (Lifting The Exponent Lemma).
We will use notation $p^{\alpha}||n$ for positive integer $n$, nonnegative integer $\alpha$ and prime $p$, which equivalent to $p^{\alpha}|n$ and $p^{\alpha+1}\nmid n$.

**Theorem.**
Let $a,b,n$ be a positive integers and $p^{\alpha}||a-b$, $p^{\beta}||n$. Then:

- if $p>2$ and $\alpha\geq 1$ then $p^{\alpha+\beta}||a^n-b^n$;
- if $p=2$ and $\alpha\geq 2$ then $2^{\alpha+\beta}||a^n-b^n$.

**Note.** If $p=2$ and $\alpha=1$ then $2^{\beta+1}||a^n-b^n$.

Your statement is a consequence of this theorem.

Some links about LTE lemma:

[What can I do with the lifting the exponent lemma?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2182155/what-can-i-do-with-the-lifting-the-exponent-lemma)

https://brilliant.org/wiki/lifting-the-exponent/